# DataMapper input schema is not reading all the XML payload

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I Have an xml payload that contains repetition of nodes depends on the response. When loading the input schema, the diagram shows only the first occurence in the root element.

I want that the DataMapper mediator read all the occurences, process them and then sending the result to the client instead of processing only the first occurence encoutered.

My XML input is as follow :

```html
<NVprotocol>
<CDMA>
  <id>1</id>
  <value>2</value>
</CDMA>
<CDMA>
  <id>5</id>
  <value>7</value>
</CDMA>
</NVprotocol>
```

But the DataMapper is processing only the first  node with its children.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When loading the input schema, the diagram shows only the first occurence in the root element.

Even though it shows only the first occurrence, It will map all the occurrences in the mapping.

I'm using the following input and output files to create the mapping:

**input.xml**

```
<NVprotocol>
    <CDMA>
        <id>1</id>
        <value>2</value>
    </CDMA>
    <CDMA>
        <id>5</id>
        <value>7</value>
    </CDMA>
</NVprotocol>
```

**output.json**

```
{
    "NVprotocol": [
        {
            "CDMA": {
                "id": 1,
                "val": 2
            }
        },
                {
            "CDMA": {
                "id": 3,
                "val": 4
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Mapping**

[image: xml to json mapping]
**Real time Datamapper Preview**

[image]

After that save and export this Data mapping inside a proxy or API, by using the **Export Composite Application Project** option.

Then send a request with the following body.

```
<NVprotocol>
<CDMA>
  <id>1</id>
  <value>2</value>
</CDMA>
<CDMA>
  <id>5</id>
  <value>7</value>
</CDMA>
<CDMA>
  <id>5</id>
  <value>7</value>
</CDMA>
<CDMA>
  <id>5</id>
  <value>7</value>
</CDMA>
</NVprotocol>
```

You will receive the following response.

```
{
    "NVprotocol": [
        {
            "CDMA": {
                "id": 1,
                "val": 2
            }
        },
        {
            "CDMA": {
                "id": 5,
                "val": 7
            }
        },
        {
            "CDMA": {
                "id": 5,
                "val": 7
            }
        },
        {
            "CDMA": {
                "id": 5,
                "val": 7
            }
        }
    ]
}
```